# If checked -> addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input checkbox

```
<label for="edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="agreed" id="edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed" name="panes[uc_termsofservice_agreement_checkout][tos_agree][agreed]"> I agree with the terms above</label>
```

and I want to add class to element befcontentleft
when it will be checked. Tell me please solution. Thanks.

```
if($('input#edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed').is(':checked') {
     $('befcontentleft').addClass('green');
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML. Is that an ID? An element (not a valid element?)

Comment: Also, no reason to put [element]#[id], #[id] works just as well

Comment: that is a long ID, but it should work. see answer below

Comment: @Kerry "#[id] works just as well" ... or perhaps (ever so slightly) better, given that you're removing an unnecessary additional check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('input#edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
         $('#befcontentleft').addClass('green');
    }
    else {
         //do something else
    }
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/9UQf8/

Comment: @Siteogra -- no problem ^_^ anytime

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input#edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed').change(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('befcontentleft').addClass('green');
  }
});
```

Comment: why use jQuery `is` when you can use native `this.checked`?

Comment: never said it wont work, i was just curious, also your code is missing parenthesis...

Comment: @Neal...yep was missing the ending parenthesis. Thanks!